# Android Wearable apk update

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a question about wearable apps on Android.
Imagine that i have a handheld application and wearable application in my project.

From what I understand whenever I install new apk on the phone, wearable application is also installed on watch (and I am not talking about installing from Android Studio, but manually wither from sdcard or through ADB).

And now my question: what happens if wearable device is out of reach or turned off while handheld application is installed? Will the wearable app be updated next time device is connected? Or I would have to start installation once again to update app on wearable?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be installed as soon, as the wearable device(s) get(s) connected.